# Selecting points within polygon AND sum up point layer's attribute

Tags: qgis, polygon, count

i have two layers:
1. a point layer. It contains a value.
2. a polygon layer.

I want to sum up the values of the points within each polygon.

I tried to do it with "Count points in polygon(weighted)" - but it's extreml slow. Not even 1 % finished after 10 minutes (and it's only ~ 50000 points!). Is that correct?!

Comment: Which QGIS version are you using?

Answer (score 4):

The DB Manager plugin now gives you access to shapefiles as 'virtual layers' AND allows you to run not only SQL queries on these layers, but SQL Spatial Functions!

So here's a quick example where I count the number of schools (points) in each elementary boundary (polygon) using 2 shapefiles and SQL spatial:

[image]

So instead of using count(*) you would use sum(value_field).

Give it a shot!